# Unable to call javascript code

Tags: c#, silverlight

In Mainpage...html

```
<script type="script/javascript">
function SayHi()
{
   alert("Oke.Hai..(waving)!")
}
</script>
```

and in xaml simpley thereis a button

```
<button name="Btn" width="100" content="Say 2!" Click="Btn_Click">

</button>
```

Then in the cs file within the button click event

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke(SayHi);
```

Yuyik, a runtime error "Unable to to invoke the method in in click event, Debug ?"

It's simple just that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A script's `type` should be `text/javascript`, not `script/javascript`.

Comment: You forgot crucial tag, I've added it for you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the method name with double quotes otherwise it mistakes it as variable name:

```
HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("SayHi");
```

Comment: Try to follow the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221359(v=vs.95).aspx) then to create the button and attach its onclick event.